# Mocking Static Methods and AEM Mocks

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, aem, powermockito

I'm using maven to build and test my code before installing to an instance of AEM 5.6.1. I've written unit tests that benefit from aem mocks using [an implementation by wcm.io](http://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/) and other unit tests that require mocking static methods using powermockito.

Here are my maven dependencies for the aem-context, sling mocks and powermock.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.wcm</groupId>
  <artifactId>io.wcm.testing.aem-mock</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.resourceresolver</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>r05</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.9</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.testing</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.14</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.mime</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.resourceresolver-mock</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.jcr-mock</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.sling-mock</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.osgi-mock</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.sling-mock-jackrabbit</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.junit.core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In my class I'm setting up the rule for the aem context and preparing some static classes for mocking:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyStatic.class})
public abstract class MyTest {

  @Rule
  public final AemContext context = new AemContext();

  @Mock
  protected MyStatic myStatic;
...
```

When I run mvn test via the command line I received the following exception:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.431 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com...MyTest
testTest(com.linkedin.aem.components.foundation.components.ParbaseTest)  Time elapsed: 0.183 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockServiceRegistration.readOsgiMetadata(MockServiceRegistration.java:93)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockServiceRegistration.<init>(MockServiceRegistration.java:55)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockBundleContext.registerService(MockBundleContext.java:80)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockBundleContext.registerService(MockBundleContext.java:74)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.SlingContextImpl.registerService(SlingContextImpl.java:309)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.SlingContextImpl.registerService(SlingContextImpl.java:294)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.SlingContextImpl.registerDefaultServices(SlingContextImpl.java:118)
  at io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.context.AemContextImpl.registerDefaultServices(AemContextImpl.java:53)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.SlingContextImpl.setUp(SlingContextImpl.java:102)
  at io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.context.AemContextImpl.setUp(AemContextImpl.java:75)
  at io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit.AemContext.access$000(AemContext.java:40)
  at io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit.AemContext$1.before(AemContext.java:119)
  at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:44)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:91)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory
  at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:121)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.OsgiMetadataUtil.<clinit>(OsgiMetadataUtil.java:61)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockServiceRegistration.readOsgiMetadata(MockServiceRegistration.java:93)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockServiceRegistration.<init>(MockServiceRegistration.java:55)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockBundleContext.registerService(MockBundleContext.java:80)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.MockBundleContext.registerService(MockBundleContext.java:74)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.SlingContextImpl.registerService(SlingContextImpl.java:309)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.SlingContextImpl.registerService(SlingContextImpl.java:294)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.SlingContextImpl.registerDefaultServices(SlingContextImpl.java:118)
  at io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.context.AemContextImpl.registerDefaultServices(AemContextImpl.java:53)
  at org.apache.sling.testing.mock.sling.context.SlingContextImpl.setUp(SlingContextImpl.java:102)
  at io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.context.AemContextImpl.setUp(AemContextImpl.java:75)
  at io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit.AemContext.access$000(AemContext.java:40)
  at io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit.AemContext$1.before(AemContext.java:119)
  at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:44)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:91)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
  at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
  at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

If I don't prepare any static classes for the test (remove the @PrepareForTest annotation), the test runs just fine. As soon as I add the annotation (even if empty), I get the issue. I'm left with the following questions:

1. Is there anything in my setup I can change to get this to work?
2. Does the aem context work with static mocking at all? (potentially with another library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by tweaking the version numbers of the test dependencies to the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.wcm</groupId>
  <artifactId>io.wcm.testing.aem-mock</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.resourceresolver</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>r05</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.9</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.testing</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.14</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.mime</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
  <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit-addons</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-addons</artifactId>
  <version>1.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.resourceresolver-mock</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.jcr-mock</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.sling-mock</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.osgi-mock</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.testing.sling-mock-jackrabbit</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.19</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.19</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```